# Unity-3D how can i see polygon count in mobile phone?

Tags: unity-game-engine, mobile, polygon, triangle-count

I searched in internet for see polygon count on mobile phone but i didn't see. I just want to see polygon count with adding object step by step.Is there way to see this?Do i just have to see it in Unity

Comment: I guess you could do it manually: find all mesh filters in the scene, and calculate the triangles from there.

Comment: @lggy Thanks for comment.Yes looks like i'll do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check vertex by selecting 3d model and expand it by click on the arrow key in asset folder as you can see in this image

[image]

you can see in the bottom right corner of inspector window vertex is given of selected model

[image: here]